# use ransack on an ready app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good day.
My problem is^ i'm trying to use ransack on ready project.
it uses diff languages and will_paginage.
Currently i get

```
No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!
```

when i try to access index action of the controller.
What should i do to make search work?

controller:

```
def index
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to articles_path(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
      if params[:q]
      @search = Article.search(params[:q])
        logger.debug '! IF 1'
         @articles = @search.result(:distinct => true).
           paginate page: params[:page], order: 'created_at desc',
          per_page: 5   # load all matching records
      else
        logger.debug('! ELSE 2')
        @articles = Article.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'created_at desc',
        per_page: 5
      end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @articles }
    end
  end
 end
```

**Update 1**
And yes, if you downvote me, ok, but could you explain to me for what?

**Update 2**
and the view

```
 <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :articles_title_start %>
  <%= f.text_field :articles_title_start %><br />
  <!-- etc... -->
  <%= f.submit :value=>'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

**Update 3**
model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :title
  validates :title, :presence=>true,:uniqueness=>true
  validates :text, :presence=>true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
    @q = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page]).search(params[:q])
    @articles = @q.result(:distinct => true)
```

I have never used will_paginate but with kaminari the equivalent works with ransack

also in your view you have var @q and in your controller you have @search, these will need to be the same surely, so maybe changing controller to

.....

```
 @q = Article.search(params[:q])

 if params[:q]
    logger.debug '! IF 1'
     @articles = @q.result(:distinct => true).
       paginate page: params[:page], order: 'created_at desc',
      per_page: 5   # load all matching records
  else
```

.....

Comment: Well, it was an error alright, but fixid this didn't solve general problem.
if i change url to http://0.0.0.0:3000/en/articles?q=fds
i get error : undefined method `with_indifferent_access'

Comment: I have updated my answer so that @q is defined outside of if statement as it always needs to be defined

Comment: Yes, i didn't notice that one.
But after editing error occurs
undefined method `articles_title_start'
as of view displayed above

Comment: does you article class have an attribute called title? you could try :name_cont or :articles_SOMEATR_start or :articles_SOMEATR_cont